# Where is the admin-sales-orders > modify Order Status code of model file?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to find the model file function which updates the order status from admin dashboard. I checked all the functions of `/admin/model/sale/order.php` file but no use. Any help would be appreciated. My store opencart Version is 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OC 2.3 the admin order info screen (which is where you'd typically be performing status updates) makes an ajax call to the front end api method `history()` in `catalog/controller/api/order.php` when you change status.

This in turn calls `addOrderHistory()` in `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` to update the status.  If you want to modify the logic you could do it in either place, depending on your needs.

The important point here is that in this version most of the order related admin functions work through the front end api to modify orders. This has been the case beginning with OC version 2.0 and remains this way in Opencart 3.

Answer (score 1):

In opencart, when order is updated it uses `catalog/api/order.php` to handle orders. so to edit orders this controller will use `catalog/model/checkout/order.php`.

Now, as you are searching for changing `order_status` ,you will find it in `addOrderHistory()` function & `$this->db->query("UPDATE`" . DB_PREFIX . "order`SET order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your admin/model/localisation/order_status.php file on the admin side. If you're ever unsure what model is being used you can also simply look at the controller file since it will load the appropriate model for whatever data is being used. In this case, the controller file for order.php is using:

```
$this->load->model('localisation/order_status');
```

And that's how you know (just a simple partial search of "status" in the controller file helped me find it - fyi).

Hope that helps you.